# Take ArrayType column from one PySpark dataframe and get corresponding value in another dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes, one called itemsets and another called rules from running FPGrowth. They are formatted like so:

```
ITEMSETS DATAFRAME
+------------------------+-----+
|cart                    |freq |
+------------------------+-----+
|[7084781116]            |10492|
|[7084781116, 2606500532]|362  |
|[7084781116, 0]         |327  |
|[7084781116, 2001]      |393  |
|[7084781116, 4011]      |489  |
|[4460030705]            |448  |
|[3800035800]            |539  |
|[3022304060]            |1188 |
|[2800021730]            |901  |
|[1380018805]            |437  |
+------------------------+-----+

RULES DATAFRAME
+--------------------+------------+
|          antecedent|  consequent|
+--------------------+------------+
|        [1686, 4068]|[2640000010]|
|[1675, 4432, 3680...|      [1673]|
|[1676, 1677, 3680...|      [1678]|
|[1676, 1677, 3680...|[3680080816]|
|[1676, 1677, 3680...|[3680044476]|
|[1676, 1677, 3680...|      [1675]|
|[7283040006, 7110...|      [1683]|
|[7283040006, 7110...|      [1682]|
|[1674, 4300000953...|      [1673]|
|[1674, 4300000953...|[3680044476]|
+--------------------+------------+
```

I need to add a few new columns to perform a calculation (to reverse the antecedent and consequent relationship, if you're curious.)

In the first, I need to add a new column to the rules dataframe that has the corresponding frequencies from the itemsets dataframe. So for example, where the consequent is [7084781116], the new column will have the frequency of that array from the itemsets dataframe (10492, via the first row.)

Next, I need to append the value of the consequent to the antecedent, and then do the same thing. So for example, looking at the second row in the rules column, I need to add 1673 to [1675, 4432, 3680...] and then get the frequency of THAT array from the itemsets table, and store it in another column.

Can anyone help me out with this? I'm pretty new to PySpark and in over my head.I tried implementing several UDFs, for example with something like the following, with the hopes of converting the arrays to strings to possibly make them easier to work with:

```
In [6]: conv_to_str([1,3,2,6,5])
Out[6]: '1|2|3|5|6|'

In [7]: def conv_to_str(listname):
        listname.sort()
        rv = ""
        for val in listname:
            rv += str(val) + "|"
        return rv[:-1]

In [8]: conv_to_str([1,3,2,6,5])
Out[8]: '1|2|3|5|6'
```

Thanks!

Comment: what does this 'I need to add 1673 to [1675, 4432, 3680...] and then get the frequency of THAT array from the itemsets table, and store it in another column.' mean?

Comment: and do you mind converting to Pandas?

Comment: @RAMSHANKERG I can't convert to Pandas because the dataset too big to fit in memory. And by 'add' I mean append— so the antecedent will go from [1675...] to [1673, 1675...]. That entry will appear somewhere in the frequent itemsets dataframe, so I need to find it and get the frequency from the other column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest these three steps:

1. For adding the frequency column use left-join on the `consequent` & `cart` columns.
2. For adding the `consequent` value to the `antecendent` array use [concat](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat) function (supported for arrays since Spark 2.4).
3. Do the left-join again on the enriched `antecendent` column to get the frequency of this concatenated array.

So in PySpark the query could look like this:

```
(
  rules_df
  .withColumn('antecedent_enriched', concat('antecendent', 'consequent'[0]))
  .alias('a')
  .join(itemsets_df.alias('b'), col('a.consequent') == col('b.cart'), 'left')
  .join(itemsets_df.alias('c'), col('a.antecedent_enriched') == col('c.cart'), 'left'))
  .select(
    'antecedent',
    'consequent',
    'b.freq',
    'antecedent_enriched',
    col('c.freq').alias('freq_enriched')
  )
)
```

Also be careful when using the `concat` function since if the `consequent` column contains Null values the result of the concatenation will be also Null.